# intel edison voice control - how to configure alsa

Tags: alsa, speech-recognition, voice-command

I want to implement a voice controlled wheelchair using Intel Edison. Basically I will say forward, left, right and stop to a microphone connected to the Edison board via the [sound adaptor](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002FI7GWK).

For the initial prototype I just want to display the output of the speech recognition to the CLI.

I am following [this](https://github.com/drejkim/led-speech-edison) online tutorial. Everything is good until the sound configuration section.

Next are the CLI outputs of the commands used in the tutorial.

lsusb:

```
root@edison:/home/speech_to_text# lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0d8c:000c C-Media Electronics, Inc. Audio Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

alsa-utils:

```
root@edison:/home/speech_to_text# opkg install alsa-utils libportaudio2 libasound2 bison espeak alsa-lib-dev alsa-utils-dev alsa-dev python-numpy
Package alsa-utils (1.0.28-r0) installed in root is up to date.
Package libportaudio2 (v19+svnr1387-r0) installed in root is up to date.
Package libasound2 (1.0.28-r0) installed in root is up to date.
Package bison (2.7.1-r0) installed in root is up to date.
Package espeak (1.48.04-r0) installed in root is up to date.
Package alsa-lib-dev (1.0.28-r0) installed in root is up to date.
Package alsa-utils-dev (1.0.28-r0) installed in root is up to date.
Package alsa-lib-dev (1.0.28-r0) installed in root is up to date.
Package python-numpy (1.7.0-r1) installed in root is up to date.
```

aplay: (GIVES ERROR HERE)

```
root@edison:/home/speech_to_text# aplay -Ll
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:1697:(snd_config_load1) _toplevel_:1:29:Unexpected char
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3417:(config_file_open) /home/root/.asoundrc may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3339:(snd_config_hooks_call) function snd_config_hook_load returned error: Invalid argument
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3788:(snd_config_update_r) hooks failed, removing configuration
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:1697:(snd_config_load1) _toplevel_:1:29:Unexpected char
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3417:(config_file_open) /home/root/.asoundrc may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3339:(snd_config_hooks_call) function snd_config_hook_load returned error: Invalid argument
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3788:(snd_config_update_r) hooks failed, removing configuration
aplay: device_list:277: control open (0): Invalid argument
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:1697:(snd_config_load1) _toplevel_:1:29:Unexpected char
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3417:(config_file_open) /home/root/.asoundrc may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3339:(snd_config_hooks_call) function snd_config_hook_load returned error: Invalid argument
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3788:(snd_config_update_r) hooks failed, removing configuration
aplay: device_list:277: control open (1): Invalid argument
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:1697:(snd_config_load1) _toplevel_:1:29:Unexpected char
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3417:(config_file_open) /home/root/.asoundrc may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3339:(snd_config_hooks_call) function snd_config_hook_load returned error: Invalid argument
ALSA lib /data/jenkins_worker/workspace/edison-weekly/out/linux64/build/tmp/work/core2-32-poky-linux/alsa-lib/1.0.28-r0/alsa-lib-1.0.28/src/conf.c:3788:(snd_config_update_r) hooks failed, removing confroot@elab_iot_edison:/home/speech_to_text# installPip.sh
```

What should I do to fix this?

Comment: `/home/root/.asoundrc may be old or corrupted: consider to remove or fix it`?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, solved it. There was some problem with the .asoundrc file.

Replaced the content of .asoundrc with the following and it worked. Followed [this](http://www.alsa-project.org/main/index.php/Asoundrc) link to solve it.

```
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw           
    card 0
}
```